# Overlapping issue when adding UIViews through code

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, overlapping

I hope someone can help me with this:

I'm building an app in Xcode and I've added some UIViews through code, I can't do it through the main.storyboard because the number of UIViews, it deppends on how many fields the database has. So, if for example the database has 20 fields, there will be 20 UIViews. That's what I've done and it works well, but... here is the issue: the UIViews overlap with other objects that have been added in the Main.storyboard and some objects like the segmented control aren't working when I try to interact with them.

That's the code I've got so far:

```
import UIKit  


class issuesScreen: UIViewController {  
    @IBOutlet weak var csViewLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!  
    var showingMenu=false  
    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {  
        let view = UIScrollView()  
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false  
        view.contentSize.height = 2000  
        return view  
    }()  

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        view.addSubview(scrollView)  
        setupScrollView()  
    }  
    //Here is when I'm adding the views  
    func setupScrollView() {  
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true  
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true  
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true  
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true  
        let firstView = UIView()  
        firstView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false  
        firstView.backgroundColor = .black  

        scrollView.addSubview(firstView)  

        firstView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true  
        firstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true  
        firstView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true  
        firstView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true  

        let secondView = UIView()  
        secondView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false  
        secondView.backgroundColor = .white  
        scrollView.addSubview(secondView)  

        secondView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true  
        secondView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 41).isActive = true  
        secondView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 398).isActive = true  
        secondView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 178).isActive = true  
    }  
    @IBAction func showBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {  
        if(showingMenu) {  
            csViewLeading.constant = -240  
        } else {  
            csViewLeading.constant = 0  
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})  
        }  
        showingMenu= !showingMenu  
    }  
}
```

This is the result when I test the app:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/n24HDvH.png],

the grey background is the side bar and as you can see, it overlaps with the UIView.

I don't really know the reason of why this is happening, and also, don't tell me to use a tableView instead unless it's possible to get that custom style (this is how it has to look like): 
[image: https://i.imgur.com/4nU97yO.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely use a `UITableView`. Of course it is possible to create the custom design - simply implement a custom `UITableViewCell` that you can design however you want.

Even if you get your solution to work, the performance will be terrible if you have many database entries. `UITableView` does a lot of optimisation like reusing cells that are not visible.

Comment: Ok thank you very much @pajevic! So, I'm going to use a UITableView then, I'll have to learn how to do it since I'm pretty new in XCode though.